# Generating Series from Lagging Data with Mutate Verb in R Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, lag

I am working with some large datasets in R, but I cannot find a way to mutate a variable with the previous value.

In a for loop, it would be:

```
df <- tibble(x=c(1:10),y=c(1:10))

for(i in c(2:nrow(df))) {
    df$x[i] = df$x[i-1] * 1.05
}
```

I tried the following but it is not working. It only lags the series one time. I need it to be lagging as it is iterating through the data.

```
df %>% mutate(x=ifelse(x==1,1,lag(x)*1.05))
```

where my method is returning 1, 1.05, 2.10 for the first three rows, I would like it to be returning 1, 1.05, 1.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the heart of your question is how to vectorize the calculation, but ultimately you can't if one row is a function of the previous row's result. There are some fast cumulative functions built into base (`cumsum`, `cumprod`, `cummax`, `cummin`) but I assume these are using a C or C++ loop under the hood. If by some chance you could transform the calculation into a function of just the initial value of `x`, that could allow you vectorize the function. For example, in the dummy data you provided, it's actually just exponential growth which could be expressed as

```
tibble(x=c(1:10),y=c(1.05)) %>%
  mutate(x = 1*y^(x-1))
```

as suggested by the previous answer

If your question is just how to put this calculation into pipe style script, then the only requirement for the expression provided to `mutate` is that it return a vector of either length 1 or the same length of the number of rows in the group. So you could do something like this:

```
tibble(x=c(1:10),y=c(1.05)) %>%
  mutate(x = {
    out <- x[1]
    for(i in seq(2, NROW(x))) {
      out[i] = out[i-1] * 1.05
    }
    out
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

The `lag` function works on the prior row as it existed before the function was called, not as it existed before the current row. To get the benefit of a vectorized calculation and to get this without a loop, you could use `cumprod` on the lagged value.

```
df %>%
  mutate(xrate = 1.05,  # make a helper column to hold the growth rate
         # method 1, using cumprod on the helper column
         x  = cumprod(lag(xrate, default = 1)),
         # method 2, using algebra
         x2 = 1.05 ^ (y-1)) %>%
  select(-xrate)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
       x     y    x2
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1  1        1  1   
 2  1.05     2  1.05
 3  1.10     3  1.10
 4  1.16     4  1.16
 5  1.22     5  1.22
 6  1.28     6  1.28
 7  1.34     7  1.34
 8  1.41     8  1.41
 9  1.48     9  1.48
10  1.55    10  1.55
```

Comment: My mistake; I should have made it more clear that this was a dummy dataset and I actually need the series to be generated from itself, not just the cumulative product of 1.05. I've updated the question.

Comment: Updated. Not sure I understand the distinction between your updates -- in the first method here I just recreated the column of 1.05 manually and then removed it.